# Invisible breakpoints in intellij

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I can set breakpoints in intellij only by going to Run -> Toggle breakpoint, I cannot use the gutter. When the breakpoint is set I cannot see it but it's there, it's picked up and a tooltip icon appears. It's driving me insane, please help

[image]

After clicking the lightbulb:

[image]

Running intellij 16.2

Comment: Have you tried invalidating the cache (File > "Invalidate Caches / Restart.."), or re-installing? And do you have any plugins installed that could be interfering with the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the `Show gutter icons` enabled in `Preferences | Editor | General | Gutter Icons`.